# How to check if user has a record in other table with laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have three tables.

```
Users: id|name

Questions: id|name

Answers: id|user_id|question_id
```

Now i want to check if logged in user has answered any question or not.
This is my query in controller.

```
  Question::orderBy('id','desc')->get();
  Answer::whereUserId(Auth:id()->get();
```

Now how can i match it in view ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont exactly understand what you mean by "match it in view".

but in your controller you could do something like:

```
$answered = App\Answers::where("user_id",auth()->user()->id)->get();
```

But just as a suggestion: I would make a hasMany Relation in the User Model that you just can call:

```
auth()->user()->answers;
```

//

Edited: If you want to handle this in the view, you could write:

```
@foreach($questions as $question)
   @if($question->user_id == auth()->user()->id)
     {{question->name}}
   @endif
@endforeach
```

super not elegant. but probably what you mean.

Comment: I can iterate over the questions in views.Now i want to check if logged in users has answers to any specific question or not

Comment: So this will check every user,suppose 1000 users has answered the question?

Comment: Thats why i said: Do it in the controller: Check which answers the user had. So instead of checking one thousand times if it matches in the view, better search the answers from the user and pass it to the view.

Comment: Thank you,i got it.

Comment: so i am doing this way
 foreach($questions as $question)
            {
                $answers = Answer::whereQuestionId($question->id)->whereUserId($user_id)->get();
            }

Comment: No. Put the logic in the controller.
Pass the users answers to the view.
Much cleaner, much better for the performance.

Comment: Sorry i am newbie,Please have a look at this link
https://kopy.io/fzFaA